# Json serialize a array with array item names

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have the below object structure

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Subject")]
    public Subject[] Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Grade { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to serialize this object using JsonMediaTypeFormatter

```
var person = new Person()
                {
                    Name = "John",
                    Subjects = new[]
                    {
                        new Subject
                        {
                            Name="Physics",
                            Grade="A"
                        },
                        new Subject
                        {
                            Name="Maths",
                            Grade="B"
                        }
                    } 
                };

     var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
     var jsonContent = new ObjectContent<Person>(person, jsonFormatter);
     var jsonContentStr = jsonContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Below is the serialized string

```
{
"Name": "John",
"Subjects": [
             { "Name": "Physics", "Grade": "A" },
             { "Name": "Maths", "Grade": "B" }
           ]
}
```

But i want the below format of the serialized string with array item names

```
{
 "Name": "John",
 "Subjects": { 
              "Subject": {
                           "Name": "Physics",
                           "Grade": "A"
                        },
             "Subject": {
                          "Name": "Maths",
                          "Grade": "B" 
                        }
            }
}
```

usually this is achieved using XmlArrayItemAttribute for xml serialization. is there anything that we can do for Json? I know updating the object structure would resolve this but i want to know if this can be done with out updating the objects, may be with custom jsonconverter?

Comment: I would highly suggest thinking twice about using this structure, as most deserializers will not handle this the way you think. Although keys are not *required* to be unique in JSON they *should*, and most implementations deserializes into a dictionary or an object, in which case duplicate keys will not really work.

Comment: Is that considered as a Valid JSON?